# Making a WAR file of a for a clean architecture (separated) backend and front end website

Tags: java, server, war

I have a website that has a backend programmed in java (in eclipse if it helps with anything) and front end that has HTML/CSS/js etc (not coded in eclipse of course).

I can't find an explanation anywhere on what I need to do in order to combine the two parts and make one single WAR file to load to my server. What structure should they be in so I could combine them, can I do it from eclipse (and add the FE files), or do I have to do it from the command line?

I have seen this link for example, but just like the other links I have found, it talks about the java part and eclipse, but doesn't talk about the FE and how I connect them correctly.

http://www.codejava.net/ides/eclipse/eclipse-create-deployable-war-file-for-java-web-application

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to build a Java Web Application that are called Dynamic Web projects in Eclipse, where both backend Java and frontend html/css/etc resources are combined. Have a look at [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.stardust.docs.wst%2Fhtml%2Fwst-integration%2Fdynamic-web-proj.html) to learn where to place your files so that they appear in a WAR correctly

You may also consider doing it with [Apache Maven](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/) that will also offer directories for java and html/css and will bundle it to a WAR file

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look to [Maven multimodule](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html) (this link is a tutorial, but I sure you can find plenty other ones ;) )

Maven is a dependency manager, it allows a multi modules architecture were you can divide you application in several parts (Front/end for example).